# Where do I host Angular scripts if the backend is a Windows service (Windows Server 2016)?

Tags: angular, .net-core

I have .NET Core API self hosted as a windows service in Windows Service 2016. On the other hand I have the Angular 6 project which works with this API. How do I host the Angular scripts on the server?

Previously I hosted an empty HTML page with scripts within IIS Server, but now IIS is not an option.

Comment: are you using .net core? if so theres a static file system built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniel say, the only thing you must do is have a startUp.cs like

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
    }
}
```

Then put your files (index.html, bundles -the .js- and assets folder) under wwwroot folder